# Why does Chrome block my swiping attempts on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, google-chrome, swipe

I am working on the beginnings of a mobile website intended for the iPad 2, which can be seen [here](http://sandbox.xylot.net/concept1/).

When you swipe the red background, it shows the blue background to the right, but resets because no content was chosen. To choose content, one must either: (a) hold the left mouse button over one of the sidebar icons (A through E), then drag to the left more than 72 pixels (any less and it will reset, as it may have been an accidental swipe); or (b) simply click on (or tap) a sidebar icon.

The problem is, while (b) works just fine, (a) doesn't. In Chrome after a short distance (perhaps equal to the minimum swipe distance setting), it shows the "not allowed" cursor and the "mouseup" event is not registered after releasing the left mouse button. You can test out the link above in Chrome for yourself.

Can anybody determine why this is happening? The relevant JavaScript can be seen [here](http://sandbox.xylot.net/concept1/js/main.js).

Comment: It looks like Chrome thinks you're trying to drag the letter links. Try setting `draggable="false"` on those `<a>` elements.

Comment: It worked! Now add that as an official answer so I can check it off and give you the credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag a link (`<a href="...">`) on Chrome, it takes a while (i.e. the mouse must have moved a certain distance) until the drag starts off. When the drag has started, you can drag the URL to somewhere else (e.g. to the tab strip to open it in a new tab), but it prevents you from using drag functionality yourself through scripting.

The solution is to add `draggable="false"` so that Chrome doesn't exhibit this native drag behaviour:

```
<a href="..." draggable="false">...</a>
```

Comment: Thanks again for this helpful tip. I didn't know about this Chrome quirk. :)